# Affect on SEO of culture in URI

Tags: url, localization, seo, globalization

My site needs to be localised, and currently I am using the format:
mysite.com/[two letter ISO country code] - e.g. mysite.com/gb or mysite.com/us
for its address.  Obviously each application under that directory has content tailored to its audience.

I have since run into the issue of multi-lingual countries, such as Switzerland or Canada.  I am fairly confident in how I have solved the problem, however I would like to know the effect on SEO if I change my URL format to be like this:
mysite.com/[language code - country code] e.g. mysite.com/en-gb or mysite.com/en-us

If the robots don't care about me having the whole code in there it will make programming for this trivial.

Thank you for the insight!

EDIT - format problem

Comment: This question belongs on [Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Apologies, I've only seen this comment now.  I wasn't aware of a spin-off site for this.  Thanks for the information.

I feel the -1 to my reputation is a little harsh.  I don't see anything on the Stack Overflow home page saying questions like this should go there.  Isn't this more their failing than mine?

Comment: I didn’t down-vote your question. Also, I  think it’s off-topic for SO because *a)* it’s not about implementation/programming and *b)* it’s about the interpretation of third-parties services (= search engine bots), from which there are thousands, and their interpretation even might change daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking as someone with about two years' experience, this would be my expectation:

Upon reworking a site, you're going to have some issues in the beginning, you always will. Every site redesign is going to cause a little change in ranking until the search engine algorithms re-decide how to index your site based on the new content.

Google's algorithm has historically targeted keywords in URIs, so long as they're short and descriptive, and have distinct content. While localization is a plus, especially with unique content, I don't know that I would go with the en-us style format unless there's only *one* page in English. See if you can come up with a more descriptive way of doing this. Maybe you could consider making subdomains for different languages? i.e. fr.yoursite.com/ca and en.yoursite.com/ca for the French and English versions of the Canadian site.

I would also emphasize that you ought to consider writing completely separate content for the French Canadian and English Canadian versions of your site. Not only will this provide more content, but, for people who speak both languages, this will show your emphasis on the customer. Besides, the culture and way in which you speak to a French Canadian should differ from the way you approach a primarily English-speaking Canadian, eh?

Be sure to use different meta descriptions for each and EVERY one of these pages, too, and possibly a rel-canonical for whichever version you view as your site's core audience.

At the end of the day, SEO isn't about PageRank, it's about the customer. That's what the algorithms have been chasing since the Google Beta in 1999. You want to create content that makes your site worth staying on.

Hope that helped!

Comment: It does help, thank you Drew.  I am already following most of what you've said there and there will need to be some canonical linking, but it is easy for me to determine which in code.  Fortunately this is a new site so I won't suffer any penalties for making the change.

The country makes the largest impact on what is served to the user as far as content is concerned, however language will of course change the UI.  I also found that Microsoft.com use the full culture code as I described, however their business probably doesn't care much about SEO.

Any other opinions though are welcome too.

Comment: When it comes to SEO, giants rarely have to worry about their own place in the SERPs because they're already established and have such massive profiles that only very stupid mistakes can take that away. That being said, tech companies still generally strive for the best UI possible. The best example for an aggressive SEO strategy I've seen is Best Buy, check to see what they're doing. If you can't find anything else, I'd go with Microsoft's way over my suggestion of subdomains. Just remember, you're at the low end, so there's a lot of ground to cover, you have to do it exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for marking this one! I also forgot to mention, for an example of a big giant doing something really wrong, take a look at J.C. Penny's. Never use black hat, it will always get you punished. If you go grey, pay attention to algorithm updates (on ALL the major search engines) to look for trends of what might be getting punished soon.

http://www.searchenginejournal.com/jc-penny%E2%80%99s-black-hat-seo-backfires/27925/

Comment: Heh, don't worry I don't intend on messing about. The content is honest, the site is honest - it's fine. I have my facebook app and page set up and we will be looking for partners to link with in 6 months' time. All the keyphrases are about the content, and the content is produced so that headers are meaningful. I was only worried about regional robots reading "us" as for America, but reading "en-us" as mumbo-jumbo. The robots do keep a track of the location of the content (as well as server, but I can't help that at the moment) and since my site is so location centric I want to maximise that.

Comment: To build on Drew's comments above, I wouldn't worry too much about your URL structure. As long as it makes sense, is relevant and isn't obviously spammy (IE mysite.com/this-is-a-keyword-i-want-to-rank-for) you'll be fine. Exact match domains and URLs aren't as important for ranking as they once were. Content is the most important, and it sounds like you're on the right track.